# What info we get from CUDA Information Tool Window

Tags: nsight

In **CUDA Information Tool Window** in NSIGHT, under warps , you will get the following table:

[image]

Can someone explain me what are the different colored region indicating here? 
I could not locate this in the user guide so I am asking here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mouse over the lanes a tool tip will show the state of the lane.

The legend is

```
Lane/Thread State  Color
==============================
Inactive           Gray
Active             Forest Green
At Barrier         Light Sea Green
At Breakpoint      Red
At Assert          Orange
At Exception       Dark Red
Not Launched       Medium Gray
Exited             Dark Gray
```

I have filed a bug to update the documentation.